# Prototype calling constructor run

Tags: javascript, prototype

Here, i want run a function in same page

```
const USER = function () {},
ACTION = function () {};
USER.prototype.set = function(data){
   db.user.insert(data);
};
USER.prototype.get = function(id,callback){
   db.get(id,function(rs){
    **ACTION.set(data); // how can i call here**
    callback(rs);
   });  
};
ACTION.prototype.set = function(data){
    db.action.insert(data)
}

module.exports = { USER : new USER() }
```

is it possible? USER.get function calling ACTION.set function?

Comment: You assign to `ACTION.prototype.set`, so call with `ACTION.prototype.set(data)`. But you probably shouldn't use classes like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possible. But, first you need to instance the class ACTION.
let action = new ACTION()
action.set(value_here)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ACTION.set` by new ACTION()

Instead

```
**ACTION.set(data);
```

Use

```
var action = new ACTION();
action.set(data)
```